# How to set active project using visual studio automation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automation, add-in

Context:
I am building an Add-in using visual studio 2010. One of the actions is to ensure an Interface exists on a related project. If the interface does not exist, it must be created.

Checking if the interface exists, it not the problem. Creating the interface is.
I would like to create the interface using AddNewItem(), but this will only work properly on the current active project.

code:

```
ProjectItem item = VsProject.ProjectItems.Cast< ProjectItem >( ).FirstOrDefault( p => p.Name == interfaceName );
if ( item == null )
{
   item = VsProject.ProjectItems.DTE.ItemOperations.AddNewItem( @"Visual C# Items\Code\Interface", interfaceName+".cs" );
}
```

Has anybody an idea?
P.S. To be clear: the Add-in is called from a different project in the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to use Project.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate() instead.  No trouble getting the right Project reference.